# Fragment Lifecycle Enable/Disable

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragment one is call three times i want to disable in one and enable in two.

on create view initialize button
and on another button disable that button how to enable it again?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btnNext = root.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_next);
    btnPrevious = root.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_previous);
}

View.OnClickListener radioYesClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        btnPrevious.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

How to re enable it?

Comment: mention some code what have you done?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking

Comment: `  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

btnNext = root.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_next);
        btnPrevious = root.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button_previous);

}

 View.OnClickListener radioYesClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

btnPrevious.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

How to re enable it?`

Comment: Can anyone please help: how to recreate one fragment suppose on a listener disable a button and again call that fragment how to enable it back?

Comment: Try to explain better what is your problem. I can't understand what you want to achieve.